# <meter> not working properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I am following [this article](https://css-tricks.com/password-strength-meter/) on creating password strength meter. This is working fine in Firefox but it is not switching colors in the Chrome browser. I tried the accompanied [code pen demo](http://codepen.io/pankajparashar/full/bFhyf/) too and that also doesn't seem to be working in Chrome browser. Following is CSS styling for the meter element:

```
meter {
    /* Reset the default appearance */
    -webkit-appearance: none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;

    margin: 0 auto 1em;
    width: 100%;
    height: .5em;

    /* Applicable only to Firefox */
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

meter::-webkit-meter-bar {
    background: none;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

meter[value="1"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: red; }
meter[value="2"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: yellow; }
meter[value="3"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: orange; }
meter[value="4"]::-webkit-meter-optimum-value { background: green; }

meter[value="1"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: red; }
meter[value="2"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: yellow; }
meter[value="3"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: orange; }
meter[value="4"]::-moz-meter-bar { background: green; }
```

Please suggest what might get changed in Chrome which is leading to this behaviour? I tried looking for any change in vendor prifixes but not able to find any.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=meter

Comment: Thanks. I am using Chrome 52 and it seems to supported. I looked through html5doctor page too but in no use.

Comment: opera 39 - the same effect

Comment: @AndreyFedorov Can you please point to a solution if you are aware of it?

Comment: sry, i not have ideas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug in Chrome at version 52 that caused `-webkit-appearance:none;` on the meter element to wipe out the coloured bar itself.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=602928

Removing the `-webkit-appearance` property from the meter causes the coloured bar to show. Please see the fiddle below for an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/t58fnan9/1/

**Edit**:
The issue link above shows the issue as fixed. However, it has been re-opened here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632510

Answer (score 0):

It actually shows for me perfectly.
update your browser and if you are up to date, clear your cache